# How can I enable formselect view helper in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form-element, zend-form2, zend-form-select

I am not using full ZF2 installation, only modules I have specified, including `zendframework/zend-form`

**From [formselect](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html#formselect):**

```php
use Zend\Form\Element;

$element = new Element\Select('language');
$element->setValueOptions(array(
   '0' => 'French',
    //...
   '3' => 'Chinese'
));

echo $this->formSelect($element);
```

**Problem:**

when in non-view PHP:

```
PHP error: Call to undefined method formSelect()
```

when in *.phtml view file:

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException'
with message 'Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch 
or create an instance for formselect'
```

**Note:**

`$this->partial()` works, as does `$this->escapehtml()`, but `$this->formselect()` does not

Comment: formSelect is a view helper. `$this->formSelect` will only work in the context of a view that automatically loads view helpers.

Comment: yes.. but with that, see my 2nd error ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a work-around - has to be done outside of view (phtml) file:

```
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormSelect;

$form = new FormSelect();
$selectHtml = $form->render($element);

//then
echo $selectHtml;

//or from view:
$this->partial($file, array('select' => $selectHtml));
```